# SwiftUI: `Text.init(_:style:)` not automatically updating when `.cornerRadius` is applied in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, text, swiftui

iOS 14 introduced the `Text.init(_:style:)` version of the `Text` View, which when supplied with a `Date`, produces an automatically updating `Text` according to the specified `style`.

This is the code I have currently:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    let date: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(date, style: .relative)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewA(date: .init() + 60)
            .cornerRadius(20) // <--- here
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, when the `.cornerRadius()` modifier is applied, the text no longer automatically updates, yet when I remove the modifier it works as intended. Is this just a bug or is there some way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every modifier applied to view may convert it in something completely different, that is the purpose of modifier. So this might be a bug, but might be not.

Anyway, here is possible solution - if Text behaves as it behaves, then keep it *unmodified* as long as possible.

Tested & worked with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct ViewA: View {
    let date: Date

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .overlay(
                Text(date, style: .relative)
            )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewA(date: .init() + 60)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I was kinda looking for a way to add the modifier to the ContentView, since ViewA is meant to be reusable and so it may have a corner radius or no corner radius. I guess I could set the corner radius to 0 however that adds an additional unnecessary modifier and parameter